# vba word macro to put a string to an existing Heading

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

i am attempting to write a macro that with find/replace a string and than move it to an existing heading. The original text is like this:

**1. Heading 1**

**ID**: abcd

**1.1 Heading 2**

**ID**: abcd

And it should look like:

**1.Heading 1 abcd**

**1.1 Heading 2 abcd**

I am having some problems with the code i tried to write, mostly because i am kinda new, but this is what i created so far:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Style = "Heading 2"
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "abcd"
    .Replacement.Text = "abcd^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

The text is not so important because i managed to replace with what i want but i don't know how to align it with the Heading style.. Thanks

EDIT: I hope i don't screw up again, sorry big :). So i have [raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te75F.png) which is the raw text and i want to process it to look like this [final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOUzD.png). I already found out, thanks to you how to replace the text, it's just that i stuck in the raw version. Thanks, I kinda own you a beer, or two

LATER EDIT: So i have 5 types of Heading formats, **1. Heading 1, 1.1 Heading 2** etc till 5, and all of them have below them an ID, each with a specific number, but the name is the same, **ID** ASD_PC_AWP_[XXXX]. I just have to get rid of **ID** ASD_PC_ and put AWP_[xxxx] at same level of the Heading eg: **1.Heading 1 AWP_[xxxx1] ** , **2. Heading 2 AWP_[xxx2]**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "ID:*^13"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    Set Rng = .Duplicate.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
    Rng.End = Rng.Paragraphs.First.Range.End - 1
    Rng.InsertAfter Split(Split(.Duplicate.Text, ":")(1), vbCr)(0)
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but with some problems, the ID is the same level as the heading but so are all ID's from the document. Is it possible to adjust you code to work only at a specific Style? eg Heading 1, Heading 2, Normal?

Comment: @Luca You need to be clearer about your requirements. Your initial thread says nothing about a Heading Style being applied to the IDs. Moreover, it depicts the ID text being re-assigned to headings with different numbering schemes, which implies the use of different Heading Styles. The question in your comment above is ambiguous; to what does the 'specific Style' apply?

Comment: thanks, much appreciation for you kind help while i was vague.Freeflows code helped me with the task i had and man, vba is hard i have to say. Much appreciation once again macro and free for ur help, time and nerves with me :P. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Do a wildcard find for any paragraph marker which is followed by ID:.

.Text = "^13ID:"
.Replacement.Text = ""

You will need to specify the style of the replacement text to the heading style because when you delete the paragraph marker at the end of the Heading paragraph you will also delete the style information for the heading paragraph.

You will need to do this with every style heading followed by the ID: text.

Updated 2018-11-01

The following code should work.  I got some hints from Macropods ingeneous code.

Update 2 2018-11-01

Revised to work with a list of styles defined by user at OPs request

```
Sub ConsolidateHeadingWithID()

Const HEADINGS                                   As String = "Heading 1,Heading 2,Heading 3,Heading 4,Heading 5,Other style,another style"

Dim my_headings                                 As Variant
Dim my_heading                                  As Variant
my_headings = Split(HEADINGS, ",")

For Each my_heading In my_headings

        With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)

            With .Find

                .ClearFormatting
                .format = True
                .Text = ""
                .Style = my_heading
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Execute

            End With

            Do While .Find.Found

                If .Duplicate.Next(unit:=wdWord).Text = "ID" Then

                    .Duplicate.Next(unit:=wdParagraph).Style = my_heading

                End If

                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                .MoveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
                .Find.Execute

            Loop

        End With

        With ActiveDocument.Range.Find

            .ClearFormatting
            .format = True
            .Text = "(^13)(ID:)(*)(AWP_)([0-9]{1,})"
            .Style = my_heading
            .Replacement.Text = " [\4\5]"
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried writing it like this :
 .Text = "^13ID*ASD_PC_AWP_([0-9]@)([0-9]@)([0-9]@)^13"
  .Replacement.Text = "[AWP_\1\2\3]"
  .Style = "Heading 2"
But nothing happens, maybe i got it wrong. And i set Wildcards = True and also Format...

Comment: That's because your question doesn't reflect what you are actually trying to do. Just like the previous question I helped you with.  Please update your question to reflect the actual text to search for and the desired result you want.  Please don't add any spurious [].

Comment: I edited the main question, hope it's better now :).

Comment: A very poor update as folks don't know what is changing unless they follow the links to the images.  Your search text should be '
(^13)(ID:)(*)(AWP_)([0-9]{1,})' and your replace text should be ' \4\5'.  Note that the \ n in the replace field will not work if you don't specify fields in the search string.  The fields are enclosed in ().  You might also need to include a .font.bold=false in your replacement logic.

Comment: Well maybe because i don't know very well how to write in down, that's why put the images there, sorry about that. I am just trying to understand vba and the logic behind all of this, in just 2-3 days and tried to explain how i could. Thanks, i will try to attach ur code and see what i receive.

Comment: @Freeflow The question before the edits is clear enough. What the 'actual text' might be is irrelevant.

Comment: We might be out of sync with the OPs edits as I don't recall the question looking like it does now when I made my comments.  Apologies to all if I came across a bit blunt.  I worked out that the OP wants to change e.g. '1.1 Heading Level 2 <crlf>ID:<?>ASD_PC_AWP_XXXX<crlf>'  to '1.1 Heading Level 2 [AWP_XXXX]<crlf>' wqhile retaining the style applied to 1.1 Heading Level 2.

Comment: Freeflow thanks, i tried your code but it doesn't retain the styles applied.

Comment: I looked at it again and at Macropod's ingenious code and came up with a solution that worked on the test document I created.  I posted the code as an update to my answer above.

Comment: yup that's the answer thanks a loooot. Just a fast question:could you tell me if is it easily to adapt your code in order to use for other Styles as well? If this isn't too much already, because you did a lot, thanks again :) (ps: asking because i dunno what will the nearest future will bring on and i don't work with VBA:(.  )

Comment: My previous comment got lost, but in case you didn't notice I updated the code to use a list of user defined styles.